# Difference between file and class file in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

One can create a Scala file or a Scala class in IntelliJ IDEA. I happen to have all my code in the file style rather than the class style. So far everything works.

What's the difference between them?

The Scala file is shown below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IntelliJ there are different File and Code Templates. These can save you some time by stubbing out some code using the file name, package it was added to and other options.

If you go to your IntelliJ preferences, then Editor, and File and Code Templates you will see all the different options.

File is a blank file, Scala Class will include the boilerplate of the package name and an empty class.

They all have `.scala` extensions, except for scala worksheet which has a `.sc` extension.